# Python type annotations from private imports (from curses)

Tags: python, types, curses, mypy

I just started to use type annotations and came across a problem using the `curses` module in Python. More specifically, `curses.wrapper(func)` expects as argument a function, `func`, taking a main window, also referred to as "stdscr", as argument. However, I'm unsure on how to annotate such a function. For example

```
from curses import wrapper

def interactive_shell_curses(stdscr: _curses.window) -> None:
```

yields the error "Name '_curses' is not defined" even though `print(type(stdscr))` prints `<class '_curses.window'>`. `_curses.window` is found in the file `_curses.pyi` from typeshed. However, I'm not sure how to import it or whether I even should. Also, I am not sure whether the best practice here would actually be to just refrain from annotating `interactive_shell_curses`.

Please advice in how to handle this case!

Comment: try `import _curses` or try `curses.window`

Comment: @azro: I have tried both of those and neither work. `curses.window` does not exist. I can import `_curses`, but the module does not contain any window. (Doing `help(_curses)` after importing and searching for 'window' does not yield any results.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python `curses` module is only a wrapper around the `curses` library. In particular this means that you won't get access to the window object for typing purposes (`_curses.window` only becomes available after the call of `initscr()`, and even if it would, it would be pretty useless because the library doesn't provide type hints itself).

On the other hand, you can't just import the `_CursesWindow` type hint from `typeshed`'s `_curses.pyi` because it is not defined at runtime. This is where the [`TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING) constant can help. If `TYPE_CHECKING` is `True`, you are in type checking mode and import the type hint from the stub. Otherwise, you are running the code with the interpreter which doesn't care about the type hints, so e.g. use the `Any` type. Example:

```
import curses
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _curses import _CursesWindow
    Window = _CursesWindow
else:
    from typing import Any
    Window = Any


def main(stdscr: Window) -> None:
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    text = 'Hello world'
    stdscr.addstr(int(height / 2), int((width - len(text)) / 2), text)

    key = 0
    while (key != ord('q')):
        stdscr.refresh()
        key = stdscr.getch()
    return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```